# how to persist data in md-dialog angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs-material

I have a page, with "Advanced Options" as button. Clicking on that i'm opening a md-dialog, which has many input textboxes and  fields. if i close this md-dialog and reopen it again clicking "Advanced Options", the data is not getting persisted. i mean the input which was in textboxes and  are reset to default.

i want to persist this across different invocations.

```
<md-dialog-content>
  <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <div layout="column" layout-align="start">
        <div>
          <div class="md-title mainContent">Policy Title</div>
          <md-switch ng-model="switchval.component" ng-change="compSwitch(switchval.component)">
          </md-switch>
        </div>
        <div id="subContentID" layout="column" layout-align="start" class="subContent">
          <div layout="row" layout-align="start start">
             Policy
             <md-select ng-model="compClassPolicy" ng-change="compClass(compClassPolicy)" placeholder="Existing" required md-no-asterisk="false"
             style="margin: 0px;">
              <md-option value="USE_EXISTING">Google</md-option>
              <md-option value="USE_NEW">Amazon</md-option>
              <md-option value="USE_NEW_AND_EXISTING">Motorola</md-option>
            </md-select>
          </div>
          <div id="box">
          </div>
          <div id="addButtonComponent" align="center" style="display: none;">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="addTextGroupComponent()">Add</md-button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <md-divider style="margin: 20px 0;"></md-divider>
    </div> </md-dialog-content>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the localStorage for this

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the $rollbackViewValue() method to revert changes but I think that is not the intention.

> $rollbackViewValue(); Cancel an update and reset the input element's
>   value to prevent an update to the $modelValue, which may be caused by
>   a pending debounced event or because the input is waiting for a some
>   future event.
>
> If you have an input that uses ng-model-options to set up debounced
>   events or events such as blur you can have a situation where there is
>   a period when the $viewValue is out of synch with the ngModel's
>   $modelValue.
>
> In this case, you can run into difficulties if you try to update the
>   ngModel's $modelValue programmatically before these debounced/future
>   events have resolved/occurred, because Angular's dirty checking
>   mechanism is not able to tell whether the model has actually changed
>   or not.
>
> The $rollbackViewValue() method should be called before
>   programmatically changing the model of an input which may have such
>   events pending. This is important in order to make sure that the input
>   field will be updated with the new model value and any pending
>   operations are cancelled.

The normal use case is to copy the model, optionally to persist the model and, if all is ok, refresh the model.

```
_this = this;
this.edit = function() {
    this.modelToEdit = angular.copy(this.originalModel);
}

this.save = function () {
    service.save(modelToEdit).then(function(savedModel) {
        _this.originalModel = savedModel;
    });
}
```

Or you can backup the model and restore when cancel

```
_this = this;
this.edit = function() {
    this.backupModel = angular.copy(originalModel);
}

this.cancel = function() {
    this.originalModel = this.backupModel;
}
this.save = function() {
    service.save(this.originalModel).then(function(data) {}, function(error) {
       _this.originalModel = _this.backupModel;})

}
```

For more Details you can see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: i could persist md-switch but not input container.